# How to create a conditional ease?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a `d3.selectAll().each()` function that animates each of the `path`s in my `svg` container. Now I would like that the first path has a `d3.easePolyIn` animation whereas the rest has a `d3.easeLinear` animation.

However, my following code does not work (no animation happens at all):

```
d3.selectAll(".myPaths").each(function(d,i) {

    d3.select(this)
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", d3.select(this).node().getTotalLength() + " " +  d3.select(this).node().getTotalLength())
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", d3.select(this).node().getTotalLength())
        .transition()
            .duration(d3.select(this).node().getTotalLength())
            .ease(function(d) {if (i == 0) {return d3.easePolyIn} else {return d3.easeLinear}})
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
})
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the index `i` from the outer function (`selection.each`), just use it in the `ease` method directly:

```
.ease(i ? d3.easeLinear : d3.easePolyIn)
```

Here, the ternary returns `d3.easeLinear` for all truthy values of `i` (that is, all indices except `0`), and `d3.easePolyIn` for the falsy value (the first index, `0`).

Here is a demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([1, 1])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("cx", 15)
  .attr("cy", (_, i) => i ? 100 : 50)
  .each(function(_, i) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .ease(i ? d3.easeLinear : d3.easePolyIn)
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("cx", 280)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

The problem with your attempt is that `transition.ease` expects a function itself. So, when you just return `d3.easeLinear` or `d3.easePolyIn`, that's not going to work. For using your approach, you have to pass the normalised time, idiomatically named `t`:

```
.ease(function(t) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return d3.easePolyIn(t)
    } else {
        return d3.easeLinear(t)
    }
})
```

And here is the corresponding demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([1, 1])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("cx", 15)
  .attr("cy", (_, i) => i ? 100 : 50)
  .each(function(_, i) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .ease(function(t) {
        if (i == 0) {
          return d3.easePolyIn(t)
        } else {
          return d3.easeLinear(t)
        }
      })
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("cx", 280)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado ! Just one thing I don't understand about the ternary is why `0` is treated as `false`?

Comment: In virtually all programming languages, `0` is false while `1` is true. In your `if` condition, you can also do `if (!i)` instead of `if (i === 0)`. Try it.

Comment: got it! I thought `i` is not treated as `0=false`, because `0` is a value as any other iterator number in that case.